# Uniqueness of solution of an integral equation [Updated]

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functional-equations, integral-equations

**Problem.** Be $f\in \mathcal{C}(\mathbf{R})$ and fix $c_0\in\mathbf{R}$ and $c_2<0$. Consider the integral equation
$$ f(y) = c_0 + c_2 y^2 + \int dz\, f(z) \exp(f(y-z)) $$
where the integral is over $(-\infty,\infty)$. Under some conditions on $c_0$ and $c_2$, it is possible to find $a_0$ and $a_2$ such that $f(y)=a_0+a_2 y^2$ is a solution. The problem is: Is this solution unique?

Let's be free to choose specific (nontrivial) values for $c_0$ and $c_2$ if that simplifies the analysis; in particular though, let's keep $c_2\neq 0$. Also, let's be free to assume that $f$ is smooth, e.g. $f\in \mathcal{C}^2(\mathbf{R})$.

Roughly speaking, the problem is how to prove that there is only one solution to an equation like $$ f * \exp f(y) = c_2 y^2 + f(y). $$

---

**Attempt 1.** From the form of the equation, it is natural to define the operator
$$ F_r(f)(y) \triangleq c_0 + c_2 y^2 + \int_{-r}^r dz\, f(z) \exp(f(y-z)) $$
and regard the solution as a fixed point of $F_r$ for any fixed $r>0$. So my first attempt would be to apply Banach fixed point theorem to $F_r$. I don't know if this works at all, even in principle, since $f\in \mathcal{C}(\mathbf{R})$, but for now this is what I have:
\begin{align} \| F_r(f)-F_r(g) \|_\infty 
& \leq \sup_{y\in\mathcal{B}_r(0)} \int_{-r}^r dz  \left| f(z)\exp(f(y-z)) - g(z)\exp(g(y-z)) \right|
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{B}_r(0)$ is the ball of radius $r$ and center the origin. From here, I should try to end up with something like $C\|f-g\|_\infty$ for some $C>0$...

---

**Attempt 2.** A different approach is to show that, if $f^*$ and $g^*$ are two solutions, i.e., $F(f^*)=f^*$ and $F(g^*)=g^*$, then $f^*=g^*$. I tried the following: Since by assumption $f^*$ and $g^*$ are two solutions, then
$$ f^*(y) - g^*(y) = F(f^*)(y) - F(g^*)(y) = \int dz\, \big[f^*(y-z) \exp(f^*(z))-g^*(y-z) \exp(g^*(z))\big]. $$
I should show that the above quantity is identically equal to zero (for all $y$). I would proceed by contradiction. Suppose that $f^*\neq g^*$, that is, there exists $h=f^*-g^*$ that is not identically zero. Suppose that $h(y)\neq 0$ in a neighborhood of $y=y_0$. Then I try to expand $h$ in Taylor series around $y=y_0$. For any $y\neq y_0$ it results
\begin{multline} 0 \neq h(y_0) + h'(y_0)(y-y_0) + \cdots \\ = \int dz\, \bigg[ ( f^*(y_0-z) + (f^*)'(y_0-z)(y-y_0+z) + \cdots) \exp(f^*(z)) \\ - ( g^*(y_0-z) + (g^*)'(y_0-z)(y-y_0+z) + \cdots) \exp(g^*(z))  ) \bigg]. \end{multline}
In the end, I should lead to some contradiction, e.g. the integrand is zero...

---

**Attempt 3.** I don't know if it is just a coincidence or not, but the solution $f(y)=a_0 + a_2 y^2$ has the same form of the term $c_0+c_2 y^2$. In other words, if we define the operator

$$ G(f) \triangleq f * \exp f - f $$

then the problem is to find $f$ such that $$ G(f)(y) = c_0 + c_2 y^2 .$$

Therefore, an approach may be to find the solution to a “Green equation” like $$G(\varphi)(y)=\delta_y$$ where $\delta_y$ represents a Dirac mass at $y$. Such a $\varphi$ would (?) unlock the possibility of solving the “inhomogeneous” case.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(y) = c_0 + c_2 y^2 + \int f(z) e^{f(y-z)}\mathrm{d}z$
differentiating three times gives
$f'''(y)=\int f'''(z)e^{f(y-z)}\mathrm{d}z$. Thus,
$f'''=f'''*e^f= f'''*\underbrace{e^f \ast \cdots \ast e^f}_n$,
*so that $f'''(y)=0$*. (Maybe a bit more here.) Higher derivtives are also zero so
that $f$ is quadratic.  Let $f=a_0+a_2(y-\mu)^2$. If
$f(y) = c_0 + c_2 y^2 + \int f(z) e^{f(y-z)}\mathrm{d}z$, then
\begin{align*}
  -a_2\mu& = \frac12 f'(0) =  a_2\int(z-\mu) e^{a_0+a_2(z-\mu)^2}\mathrm{d}z
  %%
  = 0 \implies \mu=0\\[3mm] 
  %%
a_0 & = f(0)   = c_0 + 
  %%
 e^{a_0}\int (a_0+a_2z^2) e^{a_2z^2}\mathrm{d}z\\
  %%
 & = c_0 + a_0e^{a_0}\sqrt{-4\pi a_2}+
  %%
a_2e^{a_0}\sqrt{-4\pi a_2}/(-2a_2) \\
  %%
&  = c_0  + 2a_0e^{a_0}\sqrt{-\pi a_2}
  %%
-e^{a_0}\sqrt{-\pi a_2 }\\[3mm]
  %%
  a_2& = \frac12 f''(0) = c_2 + a_2\int e^{a_0+a_2z^2}\mathrm{d}z
  %%
  = c_2  + 2a_2e^{a_0}\sqrt{-\pi a_2}.
  %%
\end{align*}
Thus the only solution is $f(y)=a_0+a_2y^2$, where $a_0$ and $a_2$
give the *unique* (and here) solution to
\begin{align*}
  a_0& =  c_0  + 2a_0e^{a_0}\sqrt{-\pi a_2}
  %%
-e^{a_0}\sqrt{-\pi a_2 }\\
%%
a_2&=c_2  + 2a_2e^{a_0}\sqrt{-\pi a_2}.
%%
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you elaborate on the first sentence? I don't think that differentiating ends up with what you wrote. If you are differentiating with respect to $y$, then you end up with $$ f'(y) = 2c_2y+\int dz \frac{d}{dy}f(z)\exp f(y-z) = 2c_2 y + \int dz f(z) f'(y-z) \exp f(y-z)$$ isn't it?

Comment: I believe that integration by parts allows you to put the derivative on the $f$ rather than the $e^f$, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Differentiation, $f'(y-z) \exp f(y-z)=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\exp{f(y-z)}$

Comment: I see. You mean as follows: $$ \int dz f(z) f'(y-z) \exp f(y-z) = -\int dz f(z) \frac{d}{dz}\exp f(y-z) = - f(z) \exp f(y-z)|_{-\infty}^{\infty} + \int dz f'(z) \exp f(y-z) $$ and assuming that the first term in the RHS is zero. So should there be a minus in your first derivation?

Comment: Can you comment on why you can convolve $n$ times without changing the result?

Comment: Since $f'''=f'''*e^f$, $f'''*e^f=(f'''*e^f)*e^f=f'''*(e^f*e^f)$. On another note, the part where $\mu$ is shown to be $0$ should come before the part where the equations determining $a_0$ and $a_2$ are given, and the $\mu$ in those line should be removed.

Comment: Thanks. You can modify your answer if you feel like it (I didn't get exactly what you mean by reordering the paragraphs). Now can you elaborate on the intuition (I guess) that, if $f'''=f''' * (e^f)^{*n}$ for any $n\geq 1$, then this implies that $f'''=0$? I guess the intuition holds even if $f'''$ is replaced by some other function. Why would it be so?

Comment: Well unfortunately , since $f\notin L_1$, one can't use the relationship between convolution and Fourier transforms ${\mathcal {F}}\{f*g\}= {\mathcal {F}}\{f\}\cdot {\mathcal {F}}\{g\}$. But it does suggest that convolution identity $f'''=f''' * (e^f)^{*n}$ can only occur if $f'''=0$.